# Checkboxes inside a table with php foreach

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a pretty much simple issue with a table i create with PHP foreach (in codeigniter).

One column inside the table has 2 checkboxes. One `true` and one `false` so when i create the table has some names and infos and then 2 checkboxes. Whenever the user clicks the `true` I create an AJAX POST call to my database to change the state of a column. But when the user has clicked `true` and then he clicks `false` I want the `true` checkbox to be unchecked.

Here is the code

```
<table class="responstable">  
  <tr>  
    <th>ID</th>
    <th><span>Name</span></th>
    <th>number1</th>
    <th>number2</th>
  </tr>

  <?php
  foreach($students as $column => $data ) { ?>
  <tr>    
    <td><?php echo $data[0]->Userproperties_UserAM; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data[0]->Userproperties_UserFullName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data[0]->UserAbsence; ?></td>
    <td> <input class="true" id="<?php echo $data[0]->Userproperties_UserId; ?>" type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $data[0]->Userproperties_UserAM; ?>" />
  <label for='true'>
    <span></span>
    True    
  </label>  
  <input class="false" id="<?php echo $data[0]->Userproperties_UserId; ?>" type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $data[0]->Userproperties_UserAM; ?>" />
  <label for='false'>
    <span></span>
    False  
  </label></td>
  </tr>
<?php   } ?>
</table>
```

And the ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.true').change(function() {
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('.false').attr('checked', false);
                  var moduleid = <?php echo $moduleid; ?>;
                  var teacherid = <?php echo $teacherid; ?>;
                    var studentid = $(this).attr('id');
                    var weeknum = $("#dropi").val();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/TeacherParousies/send_parousia",
                        data: {
                            moduleid: moduleid,
                            studentid: studentid,
                            teacherid: teacherid,
                            parousia: 1,
                            weeknum: weeknum
                        },
                        success: function(res) {
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                        }
                    });
                } 
           });
           $('.false').change(function() {
               if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('.true').attr('checked', false);
                  var moduleid = <?php echo $moduleid; ?>;
                  var teacherid = <?php echo $teacherid; ?>;
                    var studentid = $(this).attr('id');
                    var weeknum = $("#dropi").val();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/TeacherParousies/send_parousia",
                        data: {
                            moduleid: moduleid,
                            studentid: studentid,
                            teacherid: teacherid,
                            parousia: 0,
                            weeknum: weeknum
                        },
                        success: function(res) {
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                        }
                    });
               }
    });
});
```

The problem here is that when i check the 2nd row of the table's checkbox lets say `false`, there is a change on the 1st row for `true` if it is checked.

Although I have stated

```
if($(this).is(":checked"))
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using radio buttons?

Comment: @ymas nop i was just wondering why it doesnt uncheck the checkbox of it's own row and it changes all the other rows too. I know its because of the `class` but what should i do to make it work with my existing code? And i think i will have the same issue as the code above.

Comment: It changes the other rows as class name is used to check and uncheck the check-boxes and class is not unique identifier. Instead of using class name use the Ids .

Comment: As you mention, your issue is that the selector is too general.  Read the section about "context" here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ see if you can figure out how to restrict the selector.  If you can't figure it out, let me know and I'll do an example for you, but you should be able to figure it out :)

Comment: problem is with your $('.false').attr('checked', false); and $('.true').attr('checked', false);
They are unchecking all the checkbox with the clase containing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it .false and .true will uncheck all. You just need to check the nearest element.

Kindly replace the code $('.true').attr('checked', false); with this code $(this).closest( "td" ).find('.true').attr('checked', false);

and do same with for $('.false').attr('checked', false); this $(this).closest( "td" ).find('.false').attr('checked', false);